# Saving ResourceDictionary theme

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the following command bonded to my button, It's supposed detect the current used theme and change it (Dark or Light).

```
  var existingResourceDictionary = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries
                .Where(rd => rd.Source != null)
                .SingleOrDefault(rd => Regex.Match(rd.Source.OriginalString, @"(\/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component\/Themes\/MaterialDesignTheme\.)((Light)|(Dark))").Success);

            if (existingResourceDictionary == null)
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to find Light/Dark base theme in Application resources.");


            if (existingResourceDictionary.Source.ToString().Contains("Light"))
            {
                Settings.Default.Theme = true;
                Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                Settings.Default.Theme = false;
                Settings.Default.Save();
            }

            var source =
                $"pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.{(Settings.Default.Theme ? "Dark" : "Light")}.xaml";
            var newResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(source) };

            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(existingResourceDictionary);
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(newResourceDictionary);
```

and in the ViewModel (when I run the application) It should detect the last changes made with the button above and apply the theme. I'm basically getting the value from the Settings that I changed above:

```
   var existingResourceDictionary = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries
          .Where(rd => rd.Source != null)
          .SingleOrDefault(rd => Regex.Match(rd.Source.OriginalString, @"(\/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component\/Themes\/MaterialDesignTheme\.)((Light)|(Dark))").Success);

            if (existingResourceDictionary == null)
                throw new ApplicationException("Unable to find Light/Dark base theme in Application resources.");


            var source =
                $"pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.{(Settings.Default.Theme ? "Dark" : "Light")}.xaml";
            var newResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri(source) };

            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(existingResourceDictionary);
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(newResourceDictionary);
```

The code is working fine but I feel like I could make it less repetitive and shorter?

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute

> ```
> if (existingResourceDictionary.Source.ToString().Contains("Light"))
> {
>     Settings.Default.Theme = true;
>     Settings.Default.Save();
> }
> else
> {
>     Settings.Default.Theme = false;
>     Settings.Default.Save();
> }
> ```

by

```
Settings.Default.Theme = existingResourceDictionary.Source.ToString().Contains("Light");
Settings.Default.Save();
```

to shorten it a bit.